# Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on practice coding problems and i came across this task.

*Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky. so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count*

I came up with the right solution but i am not sure about one thing.

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] == 13)
            i++;
        else
            sum += nums[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In one of the test cases output is 4, sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 4   .

My question is ,in my "if" statement i incremented the counter by 1. Why did it not add the next element to the sum? Why did it skip the next element even though I'm only incrementing by 1 ?

Comment: just remove `i++` from `if` because counter will be incremented by `for` loop automatically

Comment: ahhh, okay okay. Thanks , i didn't know it incremented by for loop automatically.

Comment: Taking your quick "accept" as problem solved then, no further changes required?!

Comment: yeah problem solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(nums[i] == 13)
  i++;
```

There is no point in increasing the index; that just makes you increase your loop counter **twice** in one iteration!

So, just go with

```
if(nums[i] != 13) {
  sum += nums[i];
}
```

instead (no else here; and: better **always** use { braces }; even when it is just a one-liner!)

And as you actually do not need that index at all, you could use the for-each loop style:

```
for (int num : nums ) {
  if (num != ...
```

Even less chance for messing up your index!

Comment: well i do need to increase the loop counter twice in one interation because the task says to skip the number after "13". I just don't understand why it incremented twice in one iteration.

Comment: That wasnt in your question. Maybe you first clarify what exactly unlucky means. Is 13 skipped, 13 and the next number, only the next number? That is not clear at all then!

Comment: thanks for that, i didn't notice. Just edited the question!

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping 13 and the number after. You are incrementing `i` twice.

Comment: i++ means i+1 no? how am i incrementing it twice? sorry i don't see it

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-1;i++){
    if(nums[i]!=13){
      sum+=nums[i];
      if(i>0 && nums[i-1] == 13)
        sum -= nums[i];

    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```